# Symfony form - set DateType on Twig

Tags: symfony, datetime, twig, symfony-2.8

I have a problem with setting value in Symfony2.8 form via twig.
I can set values for text elements by:

```
{{ form_widget(form.fieldName, {'attr': {'value': '50'}}) }}
```

I would like to do the same for DateType::class field. Already tried:

```
{{ form_widget(form.dateType, {'attr': {'value': '2020-10-30'}}) }}

{{ form_widget(form.dateType, {'value': '2020-10-30'}) }}

{{ form_widget(form.dateType, {'widget': '2020-10-30'}) }}

{{ form_widget(form.dateType, {'value': '2020-10-30'|date('Y-m-d')}) }}

{{ form_widget(form.dateType, {'attr': {'value': '2020-10-30'|date('Y-m-d')}}) }}

{{ form_widget(form.dateType, {'attr': {'value': date('2020-10-30')}}) }}
```

Answers or references are appreciated.

Comment: You can achieve it setting `'widget' => 'single_text'` in your date field options, but still should be better set  default values in the underlying object.

Comment: That's more like it, and what about changing format of it to Y-m-d?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help you:

```
{% set dateNow = "now"|date("m-d-Y")  %}
{{ form_widget(form.dateTimeField, {value : dateNow}) }}
```

**Or**

```
{{ form_widget(form.dateTimeField, {value : "now"|date("m-d-Y")}) }}
```

Comment: I saw your error with form.form, but still - not working.